# Redirect Page in Subfolder To New Folder

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

All of these redirects work except the pages located in sub directories for example:

> fr/stuff

to

> fr/other-stuff

does not work

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^/?stuff$ http://example.org/more-stuff [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/?fr/stuff$ http://example.org/fr/other-stuff [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/?es/notice\.php$ http://example.org/es/ [R=301,L,QSD]
RewriteRule ^/?len.php$ http://example.org/es/ [R=301,L,QSD]
```

this is the rest of the code

```
# Use PHP5.4 as default
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54 .php

RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \.htm
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.htm$ /$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.htm -f  
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z\-]+)$  $1.htm

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^\.localhost$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])/$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

<FILES .htaccess>
order allow,deny 
deny from all
</FILES>
```

Answer (score 1):

`/fr/stuff` will redirect correctly to `/fr/stuff`
but `/fr/stuff/` and other content in the directory will not redirect.
To redirect `/fr/stuff/` you should do like this

```
RewriteRule ^/?fr/stuff/?$ http://example.org/fr/other-stuff [R=301,L]
```

To redirect the subdirectory do like this

```
RewriteRule ^/?fr/stuff/?(.*)$ http://example.org/fr/other-stuff/$1 [R=301,L]
```

You should read more about regular expression for details.

Comment: in this example stuff is actually a stuff.htm which redirects to stuff (in the other code) but I tried your code and it didn't work

Comment: ah the problem was another conflicting htaccess file